# How to display different values without refreshing the page MVC C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asynchronous, task

I have a method that is looping through a list of values, what I would like to do is when I open the page to be able to see the values changing without refreshing the current view. I've tried something like the code bellow.

```
public static int myValueReader { get; set; }

public static void ValueGenerator()
{
    foreach (var item in myList)
    {
        myValue = item;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The actual thing is I want it to read this values even if I close the form. I presume I would need to assign a Task in order to do this, but I was wandering if there is any better way of doing it since it's a MVC application?

Comment: If you are doing this to show progress on a long running task, take a look at SignalR for the plumbing.

Comment: What is your goal here? SignalR is an option but takes effort to configure.  What about a periodic ajax call?

Comment: @axlj I've got 8 different objects, I need all of them to read this values in the same time, and then I need to call an event If the specific value I am looking for is displayed on the screen.

Comment: you need [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Comment: @WKara I guess my question is: Does this information need to be displayed in real time to the user?  Or can it have a few second delay?

Comment: @axlj It has to be in real time it's supposed to raise an event to trigger an alarm so the time does matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way to do it:

- use AJAX and `setTimeout`
- declare one action in your controller (this one will return your different values)
- an integer in your `ViewBag`, some like: `ViewBag.totalItems`

**Declare an action in your controller:** This is important, because this will be your connection with your database, or data. This action will receive the itemIndex and will return that item. Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetItem(int index) {
    return Json(myList.ElementAt(index));
}
```

**ViewBag.TotalItems**: Your view has to know how many Items you have in your list. I recommend you to pass that value as an integer via `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ViewBag.TotalItems = myList.Count();
    return View();
}
```

**AJAX and `setTimeout`**: Once that you have all of this, you're ready to update your view without refreshing:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var totalItems = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.TotalItems));
    var currentItemIndex = 0;

    var getData = function() {
        $.post("@Url.Action("GetItem")", {index:currentItemIndex}, function(data) {

            // data is myList.ElementAt(index)
            // do something with it

        }).always(function() {
            currentItemIndex++;

            if(currentItemIndex < totalItems) {
                setTimeout(getData, 1000); // get the next item every 1 sec
            }
        })
    }

    getData(); // start updating
})
</script>
```

Comment: How does this meet the realtime requirement?

Comment: @axlj Would you please explain to me why it doesn't meet the real time requirement because as you could probably understand by now, this is a completely new thing for me so i can't see the problem?

Comment: @WKara  For me real time would mean that the only delay between an event occurring and the user receiving notification would be due to network latency.  At the very minimum, you're looking at a 1 second delay at minimum or 2 seconds are worst.  This is why I asked how significant a few seconds were.  Either way, I'm glad you found a good solution :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet as @DavidTansey mentioned is to use [SignlarR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).  It wraps web sockets and falls back to long polling/etc if the users' browser doesn't support it.  Your users will subscribe to specific channels and then you can raise events in those channels.

With regard to your business logic, you'll need to look into async programming techniques.  Once you start on this, you'll probably have more specific questions.